# Transfer multiple files at the same time?

Tags: networking, transfer

**Just trying to figure out a faster way to move files across my network between backup drives etc.**

Something similar to when you use filezilla ftp and you can seit it up to move multiple files at the same time. Every other option i've used like cp, scp, rsync etc seem to send and receive one file at a time.

Comment: possibly using tar with the compress option [ -z ]

Answer (score 1):

## If all you want to do is transfer the contents of a folder with `cp`, just use `cp -r`

## Transmitting in parallel offers no speed increase.

---

Let's say your LAN is 100Mb/sec. That would be ~12MB/sec.

Let's say you want to transfer two files:

- File `file1` is 24MB.
- File `file2` is 48MB

---

Let's compare transferring them in serial vs parallel.

First, serial:

At a rate of 12MB/sec, 24MB transfers in 2 seconds.

And 48MB transfers in 4 seconds.

**2+4 = 6 --> total transfer time is 6 seconds (plus overhead).**

---

Now parallel:

Since you are transferring two files simultaneously, each file transfer will receive half of your full LAN bandwidth.

12MB/sec ÷ 2 = 6MB/sec.

So each file will be transferred at 6MB/sec.

`file1` 24MB ÷ 6 = 4.

`file1` takes 4 seconds to transfer.

When `file1` finishes, 24MB of the 48MB `file2` has already been transferred.

The remainder of `file2` to be transferred is 24MB.

But now that the first transfer is done, the full bandwidth of 12MB/sec can be regained.

24 ÷ 12 = 2.

So the remainder of `file2` takes an extra 2 seconds to finish after `file1` finished.

**4+2 = 6. --> total transfer time is 6 seconds (plus overhead).**

---

6 = 6.

**Therefore, they will take the same amount of time to transfer.**

Comment: Only if the time needed to read and write the files at both ends are negligable compared to the network bandwidth.

Comment: @Jos - True. But HDDs are fast these days.

Comment: Android Dev: what you say makes sense, i have a wired gigabit lan my only two bottlenecks is hdd read/write speeds and samba with a max 30-40MB transfer speeds. whereas through terminal bypassing samba to my nas i can get 70~80MB easily or can transfer 4 files via FTP at 25~30MB each (Iperf test over a minute has a ave of 950+MB).